# Dependency Property Binding - Assign a new value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependencies, properties

I've implemented a simple DependencyProperty on my WPF control to use it in Binding.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PollingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Polling", typeof(Polling), typeof(ConverterView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public Polling Polling
{
    get { return (Polling)GetValue(PollingProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PollingProperty, value); }
}
```

The control itself is set as DataContext, so in XAML I just use it like this:

```
<ProgressBar Height="25" Value="{Binding Path=Polling.Progress, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Polling.Progress is an integer property that implements INoftiyPropertyChanged, so changes get promoted to the UI. Everything works fine and changes on "Progress" are shown in the ProgressBar as expected.

However there is a certain point in my application where a new "Polling"-instance is applied to the DependencyProperty.

```
Polling = new Polling(); Polling.Start();
```

After that, the binding is no longer evaluated and the ProgressBar stays at the last value of the old instance.

**Update:**

As my case is maybe a little bit specific I'll explain a bit more.

A Button on my ConverterView WPF-Control allows the user to start an operation:

```
private void cmdAusformatieren_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Polling = Document.Converter(ConvertFinished);
}
```

The Convert-method takes a delegate as parameter, which will be invoked after the operation is finished. (The whole process runs asynchronous.)
The Convert-Method returns a **Polling**-object which provides an integer property Progress, that provides the information I want to display in a ProgressBar.
(What may be misleading here, Polling is the name of my DependencyProperty as well as the name of my class).

As far as this, everything seems ok and the Binding to Polling.Progress works.

In my event ConvertFinished() which triggers after the first operation is done, I get a new Polling instance returned and want to use this in Binding from then on.

```
private void ConvertFinished(object result)
{           
    Polling = Document.Format((byte[])result, FormatFinished);
}
```

After this assignment to my Polling DependencyProperty, the Binding is no longer updated and stays with its previous value.

Comment: I've added it to the answer just for the readability. Do you have access to your UI from ConvertFinished by the way?

Comment: Yes I'm back in the UI thread there and can perform any operation directly.

Comment: Did forcing Progress to 0 work?

Comment: Forcing it to 0 before assigning the new value worked, yes. But after the new instance is in use, changes still won't appear.

Comment: If it's a sticky binding, the only way to get rid of is to use deep cloning of your data source - did you consider that?

Comment: In fact, I've never heard of "deep cloning". How can it help me here?

Comment: Deep cloning means creating an object from scratch. your Document.Converter(ConvertFinished) returns an instance of Polling, I wonder how does it get created?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Polling = new Polling () ;
```

you need to write

```
SetCurrentValue (PollingProperty, new Polling ()) ;
```

When you assign a depencency property directly, all bindings on it are lost. OTOH `SetCurrentValue` does not affect bindings, it just sets the current value (duh) and propagates notifications.

Comment: This seems to make sense, but sadly, it isn't working either. The behavior is the same as before.
Also, I'd like to avoid creating a new Binding in the code behind.

Comment: Did you rewrite all code-behind assignments to `Polling` (except in constructor) to use `SetCurrentValue`? Also I don't understand whatever do you need to create bindings in code for.

Comment: I only have to assignments, and both use SetCurrentValue now. After the first one everything works fine (Binding is updates etc.), just as before.
My exact line of code is: `SetCurrentValue(PollingProperty, Document.Format((byte[])result, FormatFinished));`

Comment: Do you mean that executing this line removes the binding? That would be most unusual. I'd put a breakpoint on it and check the binding expression (use `BindingExpression.GetBindingExpression (this, PollingProperty)`) before and after this line executes.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution, in this case, is **reassign** a `binding`, at this time from the code at runtime. Cause, as you noted too, the binding holds a *reference* to the object it was *first* assigned.

Comment: @Dmitry: This is what I noticed from *my* experience

Comment: Interesting, somehow it doesn't surprise me. It's extreammly bad though, as the value displayed using that 'sticky' binding can be wrong! I haven't seen it myself, but it's definitely one of the worse bugs in WPF if it exsits.

Comment: Reassigning bindings is the wrong solution 99,9% of the time. Use `SetCurrentValue`!

Comment: @Tigran agree, I had the same problem before as well.  Or if the Polling class is implemented by you, you can add reset method to reset back to inital state.  So you don't have to reassign the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, could you try this:

BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this.YouProgressBarName, ProgressBar.ValueProperty); BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.YouProgressBarName, ProgressBar.ValueProperty);

first and check if it works. I predict it won't.

There's one thing I'd suggest to change - get rid of subproperties (I understand that you use complex objects to reduce the number parameters in your dels). They've limited support by WPF framework.

Another thing I'd try is forcing your Polling property value to 0 just before assigning a  new value to it

```
private void cmdAusformatieren_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Polling.Progress = 0; // see if make any difference
    this.Polling = Document.Converter(ConvertFinished);

    if (this.Polling.Progress != 0) { throw new Exception(); }
}
```

Comment: The Polling instance gets set for the first time, after a Button on the ConverterView is clicked. Everything works fine until another event creates a new Polling-instance and assigns this to the DP.

Comment: @Roper Could you post the code from that event handler? 'Path=Polling.Progress' implies that Polling is a property, while 'Polling = new Polling(); Polling.Start();' says that it's something else;)

Comment: @Roper Could you post a simplified version of your code as an update for your question? Also whenver a good deal of 'mandelbugs' is caused by async calls - can you run you operation synchronously just to illiminate that possibility?

Comment: Ok I've updated my question above. Sorry for the crappy code format in my comment before.
As the operation takes up to a few minutes, because there is a lot of stuff happening with WebServices and other machines on the network, it has to be asynchronous.